# Accessing different versions of a Vimeo video

Tags: vimeo-api

I'm trying to get my head around the API and one thing I'm not quite sure about is video versions.

How are the different versions of the video managed via the API? I see that the response includes the `versions` data but how would you, for instance, download the different versions? Or delete a version?